# Bundling separate CSS with Webpack

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, webpack-style-loader

I've got Webpack working with `style-loader` and `sass-loader`, but can't figure one thing out:

I have two separate "stylesheet" bundles (our normal app, and a custom-skin version for a client). If I require them in separately, it'll still get output as 1 file (bundle.css). I also tried setting the sass source files as entry points, but that gave me this error:

```
ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' /Users/slangbroek/Projects/app-name/app/src/styles/mobile/mobile in /Users/slangbroek/Projects/app-name/app/src
```

for both stylesheet-entrypoints. Does anybody have any idea how to accomplish this with Webpack?

Answer (score 0):

You could use two .js entrypoints, one for the normal app and one for the custom-skinned version. If the only difference in these were the stylesheets, you may want to have 3 entrypoints, one for the app .js that both projects consume, and an entrypoint for each .scss file. All those entrypoint files would do is require the stylesheets.

Its pretty bizarre, but I believe that'd be the only pure webpack solution. Of course, you could consider using webpack in conjunction with gulp/grunt/etc, and use the task runner to bundle with webpack and compile your scss files as well.